# create-react-app, cannot make it run on production mode

Tags: heroku, create-react-app

I had a project deployed to Heroku but needed to push changes to it. The changes were visible locally but did not push to heroku, I never could figure out why. I deleted the git remote associated with my project and simply started a new Heroku project, then pushed to it.

The new project comes up as a blank screen on Heroku. I did some digging and realized that my local project is not in Production mode.

For the past couple of hours I have tried every solution I can find to get my project into production mode but to no avail.

Deleting `public/static` and then running `npm run build` appears to work in terminal, yet the project is still in dev mode.

I would like to simply start over, as though I am deploying for the first time. Is this possible?

I am a beginner and completely at a loss. Thanks in advance.